# Remove is null or is not null quotes from string in PLSQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

From my backend I am passing 2 condition(AS STRİNG 'IS NULL' OR 'IS NOT NULL') to plsql code like below:

```
SELECT * FROM CHART
WHERE CHART_PLACE 'IS NULL'
```

This sql wrong I know. Also it produces `ORA-00920: invalid relational operator` error because **'is null'** is **String**. How can i remove this quotes from **'is null'** or **'is not null'** dynamically to achieve pure **IS NULL** OR **IS NOT NULL**. I tried like CHART_PLACE = replace('IS NULL','''','') and doubling quotes like '''IS NULL''' and q'['IS NULL']' but these seems not working with it should be WHERE CHART_PLACE IS NULL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share the pl/sql code you’re calling.

Comment: SELECT * FROM CHART
WHERE CHART_PLACE 'IS NULL'                                                                             or this                                                                                                                       SELECT * FROM CHART
WHERE CHART_PLACE 'IS NOT NULL'

Comment: That’s two SQL statements. In your question you mention that you are calling pl/sql from your backend, is it really the case that the backend is submitting this invalid SQL statement directly?

Comment: Exactly I am using jasper reports. From my java backend I am sending parameters as ('IS NULL' OR 'IS NOT NULL') to produce report for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use boolean logic:

```
SELECT *
FROM CHART
WHERE (:param = 'IS NULL' AND CHART_PLACE IS NULL) OR
      (:param = 'IS NOT NULL' AND CHART_PLACE IS NOT NULL);
```

Parameters are allowed to replaced literal values.  They cannot replace any syntactic components of SQL, such as keywords, function names, operators, column names, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can't turn a literal into an operator like that.

You could make the query dynamic SQL, and concatenate this string on. For example:

```
  open cur for
    'select c1 from t 
     where  c2 ' || isnull;
```

But this makes you vulnerable to SQL injection. It's far better to inspect the input value and execute the relevant query. For example:

```
create table t (
  c1 int, c2 int
);

insert into t values ( 1, 1 );
insert into t values ( 2, null );

create or replace procedure p ( isnull varchar2 ) as
  cur sys_refcursor;
  val t.c1%type;
begin
  case isnull
    when 'is null' then
    open cur for
      select c1 from t 
      where  c2 is null;
    when 'is not null' then
    open cur for
      select c1 from t 
      where  c2 is not null;
    else
      raise_application_error ( -20001, 'Invalid input' );
  end case;
    
  loop
    fetch cur into val;
    exit when cur%notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line ( val );
  end loop;
  close cur;
end p;
/

exec p ( 'is not null' );
1

exec p ( 'is null' );
2

exec p ( '= 1 or 1=1 ' );
ORA-20001: Invalid input
```